# Update uwsgi and nginx changes without restart service

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, uwsgi

I`m thinking on making an django app who will dynamic add new django websites and static websites.
I can make all the steps , but the problem is that if i have lots of users who are trying to add websites , if every time a website is added i have to service uwsgi start/stop and service nginx restart .. the website will have problems when a user is trying to access it .
Is there any solution on how can i update the changes withoud restarting the services?
Any help or advice would be apreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

## First, let's start with uWSGI.

If you're trying to launch all of your apps on one uWSGI server, you're doing something wrong. Each django app should require separate uWSGI server...

... and there is solution for that built into uWSGI: [emperor and vassals](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Emperor.html). Just configure emperor as main uWSGI service and configure it in way that it can dynamically start and stop vassals without restarting itself. That way, if someone will change configuration of django app, only one vassal will be started/stopped or reloaded (something must happen, you can't avoid that).

## Now let's configure nginx

For nginx is unfortunately hard to achieve. First of all, you don't have to restart nginx, you can gracefully reload it's config using service nginx reload. But if you're not fine with that, there is another solution.

For that solution to work, all of your django projects must have exact same nginx configuration (if you want to create some differences between them, check if it is achievable in uWSGI, with clever nginx config, you will able to use any uWSGI feature). If this requirement can be met, just do that:

1. create config file for catching all of possible django websites (each of them must be at different domain), it can look like this:

   ```
   server {
       server_name   ~^(www\.)?(?<domain>.+)$;
       # server_name can contain any regular expression. Just remember that it should start with `~` and contain `^` and `$`
       # as you can see, we can use named capture group as an variable later
       # you can add any named capture group for later use

       root   /sites/$domain/public;

       location @default {
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
           proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
           proxy_redirect off;
           include /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;

           uwsgi_pass unix:/run/uwsgi/${domain}.sock;
           break;
       }

       location /static/ {
           try_files $uri @default;
       }

       location /media/ {
           try_files $uri @default;
       }

       location ~* ^/(android-(?:chrome|icon)[-0-9x]*\.png|ms(?:tile|-icon)[-0-9x]*\.png|browserconfig.xml|apple-(?:touch-)?icon[-0-9x]*\.png|favicon[-0-9x]*.png|favicon\.ico|manifest.json|apple-touch-icon-precomposed\.png)$ {
           try_files $uri /static/favicon$uri @default;
       }   

       error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
       location = /500.html {
           try_files /500.html /error.html /error500.html;
       }

       location / {
           try_files /maintenance.html @default;
       }
   }
   ```
2. store each project in directories that patch to them will match domain name in some way. If you want to store each project in user directory, that it belongs to, that directory name must be contained in URL.

   In other words, you must be able to construct directory to project, by its domain.

   You can hack that limitation by creating some global directory that will contain symlinks to actual projects directories.

   **Attention!!** there is possibly security breach! If someone will create directory, which path will match hostname to it, nginx will serve that directory on that hostname. Even if domain won't point to your server, someone can access it. So you should better use approach with global directory with symlinks to actual projects.
3. Make sure that socket to uWSGI server also can be created from domain name. You can use symlinks here too.